# Evaluate an trigonometric limit in $0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the limit 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x}$$
whithout using and using L'Hospital Rule

We have 
$$\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x}=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
 \to 1 \times (+ \infty)=+\infty$$
Is correct is approach?

Comment: I presume that you are not dealing with complex number. $\sqrt{x}$ exists for $x \ge 0$. So the evaluated limit should be $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cdots$.

Comment: @MathLover I think that the limit is correct, $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}$ in this case is useless.

Comment: @lxion $\sqrt{x}$ is undefined in the real field for $x < 0$. What would be the value of $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ when $x \to 0^{-}$?

Comment: @MathLover It depends on definition you use for $\lim_{x\to x_0}$.

If $x_0$ is an accumulation point for the domain of $f(x)$, and $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$ then

$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\ell\iff \forall\varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0 \ \mbox{s.t. if }x\in\mbox{dom}(f)\wedge 0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Using L^Hopital's rule (since it is in indeterminate form) in we can get:

> $$\lim_\limits{x\to0^+}(\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{x})=\lim_\limits{x\to0^+}{\frac{\frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}}{1}}$$

Given the graph $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$

> $$\lim_\limits{x\to0^+}{\frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_\limits{u\to0^+}\frac{\cos(u)}{u}=+\infty$$

This approach to me seems better because it uses the graph, doesn't rely on the $1 \cdot +\infty$ but you are right in your approach.

Comment: But the question says without using L'Hopital's rule

Comment: @JohnDoe It says "whithout using and using L'Hospital Rule" because if you do use it your arrive at some similar to the original.

Comment: Oh I see, you interpreted that to mean something like "_without using L'Hopital twice_...". Hmm. I guess the wording is a bit strange, I thought that was just a typo

Comment: Its ok I did to, but still typed the answer but either way the OP is right.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\sin x=x-\dfrac{1}{3}x^{3}+\cdots$ for $|x|<1$, by alternating series grouping, one can see that $\sin x\geq x-\dfrac{1}{3}x^{3}$ for all small $x>0$, so considering small $x>0$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{x}\geq\frac{\sqrt{x}-3^{-1}x^{3/2}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{x},
\end{align*}
taking $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ and use Squeeze Theorem would yield the result.